# Bash regex end of string

Tags: regex

File:

```
xss.filter.rule.lonely_script_tags2=(?ims)<script(.*?)>
xss.filter.rule.onload=(?ims)onload(.*?)\=
xss.filter.rule.script_fragments=(?i)<script>(.*?)</script>
xss.filter.rule.src=(?ims)[\\s\r\n]+src[\\s\r\n]*\=[\\s\r\n]*'(.*?)'
xss.filter.rule.vbscript=(?i)vbscript\:
tomcat.javaoptions=-Dasdkalslds \
    -agentpath:/opt/hybris/bin/platform/resources/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=hybris-app-1,server=local.com:9998
```

I used regex  to find that file contains strings like:

```
tomcat.javaoptions= *****Any content and Any times/lines*****
-agentpath:/opt/hybris/bin/platform/resources/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=hybris-app-1,server=local.com:9998

CHECK_EXPRESSION="tomcat.javaoptions=(.*\n)*.*agentpath:/opt/hybris/bin/platform/resources/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=hybris.*"

grep -qP "$CHECK_EXPRESSION" /opt/hybris/config/local.properties
```

but it doesn't work for

```
tomcat.javaoptions=-Dasdkalslds \
    -agentpath:/opt/hybris/bin/platform/resources/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=hybris-app-1,server=local.com:9998
```

however works fine for

```
tomcat.javaoptions=-Dasdkalslds  -agentpath:/opt/hybris/bin/platform/resources/dynatrace/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=hybris-app-1,server=local.com:9998
```

I would like to add, that online regex checker shows that my regex is ok. But it does not work with grep. Probably issue is with grep.

Comment: you have an extra 'app' in 'hybris-app' in your regex, it should be 'hybris-1' or 'hybrid-\d' instead

Comment: I corrected, but still no luck

Comment: can you include more lines that you are trying to match in your question?

Comment: Done. I corrected. Sorry that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this regex matches. You were missing \ in (.*\n)

```
tomcat.*=.*\s?\-.*\d
```

Demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/arJOxQ/3

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! I added "z" key. It solved issue with new lines

```
grep -Pqzo "$CHECK_EXPRESSION" $SPARK_HOME/hybris/config/local.properties
```

From man grep

> -z, --null
>   Output  a  zero  byte  (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.  For example, grep -lZ outputs a
>                 zero byte after each file name instead of the usual newline.  This option makes the output unambiguous, even in the presence  of  file  names
>                 containing  unusual  characters  like  newlines.   This option can be used with commands like find -print0, perl -0, sort -z, and xargs -0 to
>                 process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.